# Use Rxjs in Angular to update data in a Json coming from different Json sources

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, rxjs, observable

I have 3 different services A,B,C. These services produce each a different JSON. JSON from service A has properties which values need to be replaced with values from JSON B and C.

I have solved this using plain JavaScript but I want to use Rxjs, because Rxjs is scalable. And I want to return an Observable instead of data.

My three JSON's:

```
let A = {
    "conditions": [{
        "conditionId": "BASFD",
        "conditionDescr": "Substitute with component description",
        "pay": "P"
    }, {
        // << more items >>
    }]
};

let B = {
    "components": [{
        "componentId": "BASFD",
        "description": "Assortimentsbonus"
    }, {
        "componentId": "BBY",
        "description": "Bonus bypass"
    }]
};

let C = {
    "text": [{
        "textcode": "PAYMENT",
        "values": [{
            "code": "P",
            "description": "Percentage"
        }, {
            "code": "A",
            "description": "Amount"
        }]
    }, {
        "textcode": "PERIOD",
        "values": [{
            "code": "J",
            "description": "Per year"
        }, {
            "code": "M",
            "description": "Per month"
        }]
    }]
}
```

My JavaScript code to substitute the values `ConditionDescr` and `Pay` in JSON A:

```js
this.httpClient.get<ConditieTypeObject>(environment.url + 'bonus/' + id, {
    params: new HttpParams().append('year', year.toString()),
    observe: 'body',
    responseType: 'json'
}).pipe(map(x => x.conditions)).subscribe((A) => {

    A.forEach((y) => {
        y.conditionDescr = B.components.filter(function (x2) {
            return x2.componentId == y.conditionId;
        })[0].description;

        y.pay = C.text.filter(function (x3) {
            return x3.textcode == 'PERIOD';
        })[0].values.filter(function (x4) {
            return x4.code == y.pay;
        })[0].description;
    });

    console.log(A);
});
```

Then the result is this and thats OK:

```
{
    "conditions": [{
        "conditionId": "BASFD",
        "conditionDescr": "Assortimentsbonus",
        "pay": "Per year"
    }, {
        // << more items >>
    }]
}
```

But I want to solve this in Rxjs because I can use an observable which can be passed directly as an async to an HTML table. I don't want to subscribe first into the function like in my code right now.

I tried it with `switchMap` and `concatMap` but that doesn't work. Anybody have an idea how to solve this in RxJS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `pipe()` an RxJS `map()` after using [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) to combine your three service requests into a single Observable. This Observable can then be assigned to a variable in your components class and referenced using the async pipe in your template.

**In your component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as fromServices from './services';
import { combineLatest, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  // 1. Create a new reference for an Observable that will contain your final data.
  finalData$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    // 2. Include your various services in your component.
    private aService: fromServices.AService,
    private bService: fromServices.BService,
    private cService: fromServices.CService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // 3. Initialise the Observables from your services in an Array passed into combineLatest.
    this.finalData$ = combineLatest([
      this.aService.data$,
      this.baService.data$,
      this.cService.data$,
    ])
    // 4. Map over each Observable.
    .pipe(map(([aData, bData, cData]) => {
      // 5. Transform your data. Note: Your Observable must return a value for it to emit a value.
      return aData.filter(() => { /* ... */ });
    }));
  }
}
```

**In your component.html:**

```html
<!-- 6. Use the async pipe to subscribe to this data. -->
<p *ngFor="let data of {{ finalData$ | async }}">{{ data.propertyName }}</p>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your answer. But this doesn't solve the problem because I still need to subscribe and this breaks the  observable rxjs pattern.  I want to return an observable.

Comment: To access data in an observable you must subscribe to that observable. I am curious as to why you believe the need to subscribe breaks the observable pattern?

Comment: In my HTML code I should like to do the subsribe with a async, if I take your example it looks something like this:    [value]="finalData |  async"   finalData is in this case an Observable and not an array. Then I also don't need to unsubsribe because its done by the HTML component.

Comment: @Ben - I see. You can `pipe` an RxJS `map` after `combineLatest` to transform the data as you need it. This can all be assigned to a variable in your component class and then referenced using the async pipe. See updated answer.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I updated your code and in the transform part i implemented my transform code, but if I do a subscribe to test then it is giving an undefined. Can you please take a look ?

Comment: @Ben - without a running example it's hard to say why your Observables are empty and/or returning `undefined`. If you can put together a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (stackblitz is good for Angular) then I may be able to help you debug further.

Comment: yes I had changed your code example with an exampel but the stack overflow admins removed this I guess. I am not yet very  familiar with SO. But I created a stackbliz  at   https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kd7hhw

Comment: Your stackblitz doesnt run.

Comment: Yes I know, but the NodeJS Express services I use are not usable in a stackblitz env. I have to practise some more in creating dummy observables, else I can't simulate the code.. Tomorrow I try again. Thanks anyway.

Comment: HI Andrew I have created a new StackBlitz on  https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pbogu6?file=index.ts    this stackbliz runs fine. Can you please take a look ?

Comment: Hi Ben. In order for you to get a value from your Observable it should return a value. In your example you are doing some data transforms but not returning anything. See updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5ng3bt?file=index.ts

Comment: Answer also updated to be more specific about returning a value from the `combineLatest` Observable.

Comment: Happy to help :)